# DPDK rte_eth_rx_burst and rte_eth_tx_burst not working in ubuntu 14.04 (AMD machine)

Tags: ubuntu, intel, dpdk, amd-processor

I am using intel NIC (82574L) on AMD systems running Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel 3.13). Both API `rte_eth_rx_burst` and `rte_eth_tx_burst` not working, they always return 0. However `ipackets` show 256 and `imissed` shows too many packets when I am using `rte_eth_rx_burst()` to receive only. When I am using `rte_eth_tx_burst` to transmit only then `opackets` shows 0 packets.

I used the same NIC in intel machine running Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4) and everything works fine there. (Both machines are 64 bit)

Is this kernel dependent? Ubuntu version dependent or machine dependent (AMD
vs Intel)? If someone has knowledge on this please share it with me. thanks

Code snippet that I am using to receive the packet.

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <rte_eal.h>
#include <rte_ethdev.h>
#include <rte_ether.h>
#include <rte_cycles.h>
#include <rte_lcore.h>
#include <rte_ip.h>
#include <rte_mbuf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)

#define RX_RING_SIZE 1024
#define TX_RING_SIZE 1024

#define NUM_MBUFS 8191
#define MBUF_CACHE_SIZE 250
#define BURST_SIZE 32

static const struct rte_eth_conf port_conf_default = {
    .rxmode = {
        .max_rx_pkt_len = ETHER_MAX_LEN,
    },
};

static struct {
    uint64_t total_cycles;
    uint64_t total_pkts;
} latency_numbers;

static volatile bool force_quit;
struct rte_mempool *mbuf_pool;
static void
signal_handler(int signum)
{
    struct rte_eth_stats eth_stats;
    int i;
        if (signum == SIGINT || signum == SIGTERM) {
                printf("\n\nSignal %d received, preparing to exit...\n",
                                signum);
        RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(i) {
                    rte_eth_stats_get(i, &eth_stats);
            printf("Total number of packets received %llu, dropped rx full %llu and rest= %llu, %llu, %llu\n", eth_stats.ipackets, eth_stats.imissed, eth_stats.ierrors, eth_stats.rx_nombuf, eth_stats.q_ipackets[0]);
            }
                force_quit = true;
        }
}
struct ether_addr addr;

/*
 * Initialises a given port using global settings and with the rx buffers
 * coming from the mbuf_pool passed as parameter
 */
static inline int
port_init(uint16_t port, struct rte_mempool *mbuf_pool)
{
    struct rte_eth_conf port_conf = port_conf_default;
    const uint16_t rx_rings = 1, tx_rings = 1;
    uint16_t nb_rxd = RX_RING_SIZE;
    uint16_t nb_txd = TX_RING_SIZE;
    int retval;
    uint16_t q;
    struct rte_eth_dev_info dev_info;
    struct rte_eth_txconf txconf;

    if (!rte_eth_dev_is_valid_port(port))
        return -1;

    rte_eth_dev_info_get(port, &dev_info);
    if (dev_info.tx_offload_capa & DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MBUF_FAST_FREE)
        port_conf.txmode.offloads |=
            DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MBUF_FAST_FREE;

    retval = rte_eth_dev_configure(port, rx_rings, tx_rings, &port_conf);
    if (retval != 0)
        return retval;

    retval = rte_eth_dev_adjust_nb_rx_tx_desc(port, &nb_rxd, &nb_txd);
    if (retval != 0) {
        printf("Error in adjustment\n");
        return retval;
    }

    for (q = 0; q < rx_rings; q++) {
        retval = rte_eth_rx_queue_setup(port, q, nb_rxd,
                rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port), NULL, mbuf_pool);
        if (retval < 0) {
            printf("RX queue setup prob\n");
            return retval;
        }
    }

    txconf = dev_info.default_txconf;
    txconf.offloads = port_conf.txmode.offloads;
    for (q = 0; q < tx_rings; q++) {
        retval = rte_eth_tx_queue_setup(port, q, nb_txd,
                rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port), &txconf);
        if (retval < 0)
            return retval;
    }
    
    retval  = rte_eth_dev_start(port);
    if (retval < 0) {
        printf("Error in start\n");
        return retval;
    }


    rte_eth_macaddr_get(port, &addr);
    printf("Port %u MAC: %02"PRIx8" %02"PRIx8" %02"PRIx8
            " %02"PRIx8" %02"PRIx8" %02"PRIx8"\n",
            (unsigned)port,
            addr.addr_bytes[0], addr.addr_bytes[1],
            addr.addr_bytes[2], addr.addr_bytes[3],
            addr.addr_bytes[4], addr.addr_bytes[5]);

    rte_eth_promiscuous_enable(port);

    return 0;
}


/*
 * Main thread that does the work, reading from INPUT_PORT
 * and writing to OUTPUT_PORT
 */
static  __attribute__((noreturn)) void
lcore_main(void)
{
    uint16_t port;
    struct ether_hdr *eth_hdr;
    //struct ether_addr addr;

    //rte_eth_macaddr_get(portid, &addr);
    struct ipv4_hdr *ipv4_hdr;
    int32_t i;
    RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(port)
    {
    if (rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port) > 0 &&
                rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port) !=
                        (int)rte_socket_id())
            printf("WARNING, port %u is on remote NUMA node to "
                    "polling thread.\n\tPerformance will "
                    "not be optimal.\n", port);
    }
    printf("\nCore %u forwarding packets.  [Ctrl+C to quit]\n",
            rte_lcore_id());

    for (;;) {
        RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(port) {
            struct rte_mbuf *bufs[BURST_SIZE];
            const uint16_t nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(port, 0,bufs, BURST_SIZE);
            for(i  = 0; i < nb_rx; i++) {
                ipv4_hdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod_offset(bufs[i], struct ipv4_hdr *, sizeof(struct ether_hdr));
                printf("Packet ip received %d\n", ipv4_hdr->src_addr);
            }

            if (unlikely(nb_rx == 0))
                continue;
            const uint16_t nb_tx = 0; // = rte_eth_tx_burst(port ^ 1, 0, bufs, nb_rx);
            if (unlikely(nb_tx < nb_rx)) {
                uint16_t buf;

                for (buf = nb_tx; buf < nb_rx; buf++)
                    rte_pktmbuf_free(bufs[buf]);
            }
        }
        if(force_quit)
            break;
    }
}

/* Main function, does initialisation and calls the per-lcore functions */
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint16_t nb_ports;
    uint16_t portid, port;

    /* init EAL */
    int ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);

    if (ret < 0)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error with EAL initialization\n");
    argc -= ret;
    argv += ret;
    force_quit = false;
        signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
        signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);
    nb_ports = rte_eth_dev_count_avail();
    printf("size ordered %lld\n", NUM_MBUFS *nb_ports);
    mbuf_pool = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("MBUF_POOL",
        NUM_MBUFS * nb_ports, MBUF_CACHE_SIZE, 0,
        RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id());
    if (nb_ports < 1)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error: number of ports must be greater than %d\n", nb_ports);

    if (mbuf_pool == NULL)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot create mbuf pool\n");

    // initialize all ports 
    RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(portid)
        if (port_init(portid, mbuf_pool) != 0)
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot init port %"PRIu8"\n",
                    portid);
    if (rte_lcore_count() > 1)
        printf("\nWARNING: Too much enabled lcores - "
            "App uses only 1 lcore\n");

    // call lcore_main on master core only 
    lcore_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost certainly not because of an AMD CPU specifically, and chipset / PCIe-bus differences are unlikely to account for a difference either.  Can you show a [mcve] of how you used the API you're talking about?  Any reason you're using a 4-year-old version of Linux?  Have you tried at least booting a newer distro on the problematic hardware, maybe from a USB stick or other live image?

Comment: @PeterCordes posted the code below, please have a look. yes I need to use openCL on the same system and it seems amd graphics driver that supports openCL doesnt work on recent versions. Latest version that works for opencl is 14.04

Comment: [edit] it into your question, don't post it as an answer (because it's not)!  Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Comment: @PeterCordes shall I post full code?

Comment: Probably a good idea to make a [mcve] that's actually *complete, that someone could copy/paste and build on their own machine, if possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes posted the code. For transmission testpmd provided by DPDK can be used from other machine to check.

Comment: IMO the code does not matter. It’s either compilation process or the environment. Try to recompile DPDK and your app on the same host you run it. Also try to use vfio-pci instead of igb-uio or vice versa...

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy I tried with ubuntu 16.04 along with vfio-pci and it worked. However it is not working on ubuntu 14.04 with any driver. Is there anything specific with ubuntu 14.04 and intel controller 82574L

Comment: Sure, 82574L is an old and just 1Gbps NIC. DPDK should work with it, but I doubt there is someone in the world testing each DPDK release with this NIC on AMD platform. Check the dmesg for some clues...

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy sure will do that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem of ethernet card (82574L) with ubuntu 14.04. With ubuntu 16.04 it is working fine.